# Can I restrict download when my macbook is being hot spotted?

Tags: wifi, tethering

I plan to stick an NFC tag on my macbook so that I can just click my phone on it to create a Wifi Hotspot which my laptop will automatically connect to.

The only problem I can think of though is that I have restricted data on my phone plan therefore I don't want the laptop to be doing anything like syncing with my dropbox, downloading system updates etc.

Is there a way I can configure the macbook so that if using a certain WIFI network, it will restrict the traffic to only web browsing traffic.

Answer (score 2):

### [Little Snitch](http://obdev.at/)

Little Snitch has profiles that you can switch to which can contain custom network rules.

For example, you can create one profile that is bound to your home network that allows all incoming/outgoing connections for all applications, then create a second profile that allows all connections for Safari, but blocks all connections from other apps.

[image]
[image]

Alternatively, you can request that applications ask for connection when not connected to your home network.

These profiles can be switched through the menu bar icon, or automatically upon joining a certain network.

[image]